# how to get next result from mysql in php (after certain ID)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not sure how to manage this sql/php problem.

I have an sql query

```
SELECT * 
FROM   blogimage 
       INNER JOIN blog 
               ON blogimage.blog_id = blog.blog_id 
WHERE  blog.active = '1' 
ORDER  BY blog.date DESC, 
          blog.blog_id DESC, 
          blogimage.position ASC
```

It gives me a list of results (say 100 result)

I want to say: IN THE ORDER described in the sql query above, find the blogimage_id = 1234 and give me the next blogimage_id result after that one.

Not sure if I'm explaining my question properly.

and how do I store that in a PHP variable?

Can that be done?

EXAMPLE RESULT OF MY QUERY

```
blogimage_id
2171
2162
2163
2170
2164
```

SO if I want to check blogimage_id = 2170, I need to get the result 2164. So adding WHERE blogimage_id > 2170 won't work...

Comment: do you need help with the query or reading the result on php? because those are very different questions

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza the query works, I just don't know how to say : find blogimage_id = XXXX and pull the next result after that in the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** If you have not just id of the item, but also `blog.date` and `blogimage.position`, then you can use this query:

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    blogimage INNER JOIN blog USING(blog_id)
WHERE
    blog.active = '1' 
    AND blog.date <= :date 
    AND blog.blog_id < :id 
    AND blogimage.position < :position
ORDER BY 
    blog.date DESC, 
    blog.blog_id DESC, 
    blogimage.position ASC
LIMIT 1
```

`:date` - a date of the item
`:id` - its ID
`:position` - blogimage.position

**2.** If you don't, then you need retrieve all the IDs in the same order from the table first:

```
SELECT
    blog_id
FROM
    blogimage INNER JOIN blog USING(blog_id)
WHERE
    blog.active = '1'
ORDER BY 
    blog.date DESC, 
    blog.blog_id DESC, 
    blogimage.position ASC
```

This query should be very fast, because it uses primary key.

And then programmatically get the ID you need:

```
$ids = array_column('blog_id', $result); // $result - the result of the query above
$key = array_search($id, $ids); // $id - the given ID
if (false !== $key && array_key_exists($key+1, $ids)) {
    $idYouNeed = $ids[$key+1]; // this is what you want
} else {
    $idYouNeed = null; // there is no given ID in the table or it's the last one
}
```

Comment: that won't work, I don't have a specefic date or id to put in the where, it's just a specefic ORDER to pull the results... Maybe I should put all the results in a PHP array, and from the array, find the result AFTER my id... wouldn't that work?

Comment: @user3011784 Yes, then you should do as I've described as a second option. I will update my answer in a minute and will add the proper code for doing this.

Comment: @user3011784 You are welcome =). I've also updated the code a bit.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your question properly you need to limit your sql to give you the second record? to achieve that you need to add `limit` clause

```
select * from blogimage INNER JOIN blog ON blogimage.blog_id = blog.blog_id WHERE blog.active = '1' order by blog.date DESC, blog.blog_id DESC, blogimage.position ASC limit 1,1
```

Comment: no, I need the next one after a specefic blogimage ID that I define.. It could be the 5th one, the 35th one.. etc.. not necessarily on top

Comment: then add order on blogimage_id

Comment: I've updated my question with an example, not sure the suggestion of ORDER on blogimage_id would work

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM   blogimage 
       INNER JOIN blog 
               ON blogimage.blog_id = blog.blog_id 
WHERE  blog.active = '1' 
  AND  blogimage_id > 1234
ORDER  BY blog.date DESC, 
          blog.blog_id DESC, 
          blogimage.position ASC 
limit 1,1
```

Comment: no, that's not it, the next result might be a blogimage_id < than 1234 since the order of my query is by blog.date DESC, 
          blog.blog_id DESC, 
          blogimage.position ASC

not by blogimage_id

Comment: Ok then I fix the `order by`,

Comment: no, that won't work... I've updated my question with an example, you'll see what I mean

Comment: what table has blogimage_id field?

Comment: blogimage has the field blogimage_id